# Using a glyphicon as a li bullet point in Bootstrap 3/Rails and HAML

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I'm trying to do a ul with each li having glyphicon-ok instead of the normal bullets.

Code I'm using is:

```
    %li.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok ok sign?
```

Which is outputting the icon but the text is showing in (I'm guessing) times new roman. When I inspect the css it says the font is still 'Glyphicon'.

I've read HAML isn't ideal to use for formatting content, and I'm guessing this is why.

Any ideas as to what I need to use to get the text to respect my custom font but still retain the ability to use glyphicons?

Many thanks

Comment: For those looking to do this in plain HTML/CSS (not HAML) there is a similar question I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196980/using-a-glyphicon-as-an-li-bullet-point-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you writing text inside a li with a glyphicon-ok image as background? if you need a link or anything nest it inside glyphicon li like

```
%li.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok
  %span your text
```

and then target inner span to use your custom css

or your can do other way around using li inside a span

```
%span.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok
  %li your text
```

Comment: Hi user, re "Why are you writing text inside a li with a glyphicon-ok image as background?" - I didn't realise I was, I've never used glyphicons before. What do you mean by 'target inner span to use your custom css'? Would you mind giving an example of the css? Is it literally .span {font-family: x'} in my custom.scss.css?

Comment: if you'll do "%li.gylphicon.glyphicon-ok your text" then what it will do is apply the li's background image as glyphicon-ok image and your text will be on top of that image and i dont think you want that so better would be to nest your text inside it..and then you can give class or id whatever you like to your text element and then target it as a normal element e.g if you give it a class text then write .text{font-family: your custom fonts}

Comment: Legend - thank you. I'd not put the .text class on the span. What I've now got that works is;  %li.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok
                %span.text your text