# Using a Glyphicon as an LI bullet point (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons, bulletedlist

How can I change the bullet points in an HTML list and use the glyphicons that come with Bootstrap 3?

So that:

```html
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Displays as:

```
 [icon]  Facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, numquam eius modi
         omnis dolor repellendus. Non numquam eius modi numam dolor omnis 
         tempora incidunt ut labore.

 [icon]  Facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, numquam eius modi
         omnis dolor repellendus. Non numquam eius modi numam dolor omnis 
         tempora incidunt ut labore.
```

I would prefer ***not*** to have to inject extra HTML such as this...

```html
<ul>
    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> ...</li>
    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> ...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This isn't too difficult with a little CSS, and is *much* better than using an image for the bullet since you can scale it and colour it and it will keep sharp at all resolutions.

1. Find the character code of the glyphicon by opening the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) and inspecting the character you want to use.

   [image: Inspecting a glyphicon]
2. Use that character code in the following CSS

   ```
   li {
       display: block;
   }

   li:before {
       /*Using a Bootstrap glyphicon as the bullet point*/
       content: "\e080";
       font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
       font-size: 9px;
       float: left;
       margin-top: 4px;
       margin-left: -17px;
       color: #CCCCCC;
   }
   ```

   You may like to tweak the colour and margins to suit your font size and taste.

#### [View Demo & Code](https://jsfiddle.net/wp67vxau/1/)

Comment: Is there any difference regarding the use of margins vs. paddings in your example?

Comment: One thing to bear in mind using this method is that it will break indentation unless a negative margin is applied to the `before` pseudo-element.

Comment: Looks pretty sweet, but how can this be done without messing up the navbar?

Answer (score 36):

If anyone is coming here looking to do this with Font Awesome Icons (like I was) view here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>as bullets</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-square"></i>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

The `fa-ul` and `fa-li` classes easily replace default bullets in unordered lists.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with Bootstrap. The Font-Awesome styles don't play nicely with Bootstrap's.

Comment: @3noch what do you mean by "does not work with Bootstrap"? The above will not work with Glyphicons, that's why I mentioned "If you are looking to do this with Font Awesome Icons".

Comment: Yep you're right. Turns out something else was breaking this for me, but it does seem to work by itself. Thanks.

Comment: @FastTrack - How about making this inline(horizontally)

Comment: Worked like a charm. But it loads async.

Comment: Huh. This must have changed with Font Awesome 5. The markup in this answer results in bullets that are not correctly centered vertically relative to the associated text.  See my answer for the FA 5 markup.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using a simplified version (just using position relative) based on @SimonEast answer:

```
li:before {
    content: "\e080";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    top: 3px;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a different icon for each list-item, I suggest adding icons in HTML instead of using a pseudo element to keep your CSS down. It can be done quite simply as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li><span><i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb-outline"></i></span>An electric light with a wire filament heated to such a high temperature that it glows with visible light</li>
  <li><span><i class="mdi mdi-clipboard-check-outline"></i></span>A thin, rigid board with a clip at the top for holding paper in place.</li>
  <li><span><i class="mdi mdi-finance"></i></span>A graphical representation of data, in which the data is represented by symbols, such as bars in a bar chart, lines in a line chart, or slices in a pie chart.</li>
  <li><span><i class="mdi mdi-server"></i></span>A system that responds to requests across a computer network worldwide to provide, or help to provide, a network or data service.</li>
</ul>
```

-

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul>li {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  left: -2em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

[image]

In this case I used [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

[**VIEW DEMO**](https://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/NLJReq)

Answer (score 1):

If you want happen to be using LESS it can be achieved like so:

```
li {
    .glyphicon-ok();

    &:before {            
        .glyphicon();            
        margin-left:-25px;
       float:left;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Font Awesome 5, the markup is a bit more complex than the previouis answer.  Per [the FA documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list), the markup should be:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```