# is it possible to use different list specifier in li tag

Tags: html, css

I'm using ✈ as list list specifier, it looks nice for my project when it is in single line , but for mobile view (in multiple line of a list) it looks bit ugly . do you have some remedies .. thank you

Actual view :
 ✈ this is what my problem with li tags
 please give me some remedies.
 ✈ this is what my problem with li tags
 please give me some remedies.

Expected view:
 ✈ This  looks awesome to display
     is there anyway to do this.
 ✈ This  looks awesome to display
     is there anyway to do this.

Comment: You should always show us the code you are using.

Comment: please provide a screenshot of your mobile view

Comment: In case you're looking for glyphicon list specifier, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196980/using-a-glyphicon-as-an-li-bullet-point-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of different ways to achieve this.

Option 1. `CSS Tables`

---

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

li:before {
  content: '✈ ';
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
</ul>
```

Option 2.  `absolute` and `relative` positions

---

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

li:before {
  content: '✈ ';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
</ul>
```

Option 3. `Flexbox`

---

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}

li:before {
  content: '✈ ';
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks man ... your code run's as what I expected ... and for the very first time I received one positive like for this question .... happy ... more happy

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to use table(without border) with bootstrap.

```
 <style>
 table tr td{
 vertical-align:top;
 text-align:left;
 }
</style>

<table>
 <tr>
 <td>✈ </td>
 <td>This looks awesome to display</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>✈ </td>
 <td>This looks awesome to display</td>
 </tr> 
 </table>
```