# Add Glyphicon to Every Button (bootstrap 3.5)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'd like to add a glyphicon after the text on all my default buttons.

I found how to include the glyphicon in lists here:
[Using a Glyphicon as an LI bullet point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196980/using-a-glyphicon-as-an-li-bullet-point-bootstrap-3)

I tried applying this to buttons, but I haven't got it right

```
.btn-default button:after {
    content: "\e080";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: #0099FF;
}
```

I realise I can add it like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="testpage.aspx">
    Learn more
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

But I'd prefer not to have to add it each time.  I'd also like to set the colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Button Style with Gylph-icons]

I thing you might wants above image Output for your all the buttons.

For that you need to just write simple css :after class css to apply on all default buttons after text:

```
.btn-default:after {
    content: "\e080";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 6px 5px;
    color: #0099FF;
}
```

this will work for your all buttons as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is the correct way of doing it:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
```

To give it a different colour just add a `class` or reference the span by using a `selector` and give the colour in css.

```
.color-red { 
    color:#FF0000;
}
```